# Set conditional make options in the robot framework

Tags: robotframework

In my robot file for a specific test, I've defined the variable *uarts_to_test* to a list of numeric values under variables:

```
*** Variables ***
${uarts_to_test}    ['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

Now I would like to loop though this list, and create the define -DTEST_UART# where # is the uart index, for every number listed in *uarts_to_test*. I would also like to add all of these defines to the variable ${make_options}. I've tried to create a simple routine under keywords:

```
*** Keywords ***
Determine which uarts to test
[Arguments]    @{uarts_to_test}
:FOR    ${item}    IN    @{uarts_to_test}
\    IF List Should Contain Value ${i}
\        ${make_options} = ${make_options} -DTEST_UART${i}
```

but I only get the error:

```
Variable '${make_options}' not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. I return make options as a string and also as a list in case additional logic is needed with the items in the list.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections    

*** Variables ***
${uarts_to_test}    ['0', '1', '2', '3']

*** Test Cases ***
MakeOptionsTest
    ${make_options}    ${make_optionsList}    Determine which uarts to test    ${uarts_to_test}
    Log    ${make_options}
    Log List    ${make_optionsList}       
        
*** Keywords ***
Determine which uarts to test
    [Arguments]    ${uarts_to_test}
    ${make_optionsList}    Create List    
    ${uarts_to_test}    Evaluate    ${uarts_to_test}
    :FOR    ${item}    IN    @{uarts_to_test}
    \    Append To List    ${make_optionsList}    -DTEST_UART${item}
    ${make_options}   Evaluate    " ".join(${make_optionsList})
    [Return]    ${make_options}    ${make_optionsList}
```

This outputs in the console:

> 20210602 23:24:59.595 : INFO : -DTEST_UART0 -DTEST_UART1 -DTEST_UART2
> -DTEST_UART3 20210602 23:24:59.596 : INFO : List length is 4 and it contains following items: 0: -DTEST_UART0 1: -DTEST_UART1 2:
> -DTEST_UART2 3: -DTEST_UART3

Comment: this worked, thank you! Though I'm wondering what the line `${uarts_to_test}    Evaluate    ${uarts_to_test}` is needed for?

Comment: "what the line ${uarts_to_test}    Evaluate    ${uarts_to_test} is needed for?"-> its used to convert the string  value of the scalar ${uarts_to_test} to a list, so that you can iterate through the items in it. Without it the type of  ${uarts_to_test}  is just a pure string.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find ${i} in your code. There is also no declaration of ${make_options} that is probobaly why it is not found. You can use collection library, create list and append the items to it. like so

```
***Settings***
    Library    Collections
    
    *** Variables ***
    @{uarts_to_test}    0    1    2    3
    
    ***Test Cases***
    test
        @{make_options}=    Create List
        FOR    ${uart}    IN    @{uarts_to_test} 
            Append To List    ${make_options}    -DTEST_UART${uart}
        END
        Log    ${make_options}
```

this will be in the log of your ${make_options}:

```
['-DTEST_UART0', '-DTEST_UART1', '-DTEST_UART2', '-DTEST_UART3']
```

Comment: I tried your solution but `${make_options}` has extra 'u's, and I don't understand why... `[u'-DTEST_UART0', u'-DTEST_UART2', u'-DTEST_UART3']`

Comment: Though I put `Determine which uart to test` under *** Keywords ***.

Answer (score 0):

from the error `Variable '${make_options}' not found.` it says you are assigning variable `${make_options}`, before defining its value.

if you take example of first iteration of loop, your variable `${make_options}` is not defined before and you are assigning it to a variable.

you can simply define a variable `${mytext}` and concatinate it in loop, like below:

```
*** Setting ***
Documentation     test1


*** Variables ***
@{uarts_to_test}    0    1    2    3    4
${mytext}    'DTEST_UART'

*** Test Cases ***
demo testing
    Determine which uarts to test    @{uarts_to_test}


*** Keywords ***
Determine which uarts to test
    [Arguments]    @{uarts_to_test}
    FOR    ${item}    IN    @{uarts_to_test}
    \    ${make_options}=     Catenate     ${mytext}    ${item}
    \    Log To Console     ${make_options}
```

console output:

```
'DTEST_UART' 0
'DTEST_UART' 1
'DTEST_UART' 2
'DTEST_UART' 3
'DTEST_UART' 4
```